Integral $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$ exactly
Wolfram alpha does it exactly to be $\dfrac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}$. How would I show this?
Are there some tricks to do it?
Edit: tried king's rule, tried trig sub, got $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\sin t)^{\frac{3}{2}}(\cos t)^{\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm dt$, tried $u=\sqrt{x \sqrt{1-x^2}}$, tried $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. All don't work.
Edit 2: trig sub, got $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\sin t)^{\frac{3}{2}}(\cos t)^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm dt$, this method works.

If you want any further help, you will need to put more effort into your question. For example, what have you tried? Where did this fall short, etc.

Use the gamma(beta) function to compute it explicitly.

Required to show $\int_0^1 2\sqrt{y\sqrt{1-y^2}} dy = \dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$.
Let $y=\cos t $, $dy=-\sin t dt$.
Integral becomes $\begin{aligned}[t]
\int_0^1 2\sqrt{y\sqrt{1-y^2}} dy &= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} (-\sin t) 2\sqrt{\sin t\cos t} dt\\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\sin t)^{\frac{3}{2}}(\cos t)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= B\left(\dfrac{5}{4},\dfrac{3}{4}\right)\\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}$
As required

@Yves Daoust You just divide by two on both sides and you get the right answer. Please follow stackexchange common sense and provide explanation of why it is a wrong answer.

+1 This answer is correct. I have verified each step. Please don't worry about the deleted user's comment.

Substitute $x=\frac {1}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \sqrt{x \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx\\
=&\ 2\int_0^\infty \frac {t^{4}}{(1+t^4)^2}dt
= \frac12 \int_0^\infty t\ d\left( \frac {1}{1+t^4}\right)\\
\overset{ibp}=& \ \frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac {1}{1+t^4}dt=\frac12\cdot \frac\pi{2\sqrt2}=\frac\pi{4\sqrt2}
\end{align}

Try polar coordinates.
$$\begin{align}
y^4&=x^2(1-x^2)\\
r^4\sin^4\theta&=r^2\cos^2\theta\left(1-r^2\cos^2\theta\right)\\
r^2\sin^4\theta&=\cos^2\theta\left(1-r^2\cos^2\theta\right)\\
r^2\sin^4\theta&=\cos^2\theta-r^2\cos^4\theta\\
r^2&=\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta}\\
r^2&=\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\tan^4\theta+1}
\end{align}$$
So your region's area is:
$$\begin{align}
&\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{\sec^2\theta/\left(\tan^4\theta+1\right)}}r\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\tan^4\theta+1}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_{u=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^4+1}\,du\\
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?
